# Is the sigma algebra induced by a family of random variables same as the one induced by the random element?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Maybe a silly question. Just wondering can one interpret the $\sigma$-algebra ($A$ is an index set)
$$
\sigma\{X_{\alpha}:\alpha\in A\}
$$
as the $\sigma$-algebra induced by the random element $X$ (i.e., $X(\alpha)=X_{\alpha}$) equipped with the product $\sigma$-algebra.

So in particular, is the natural filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$ at time $t$ of a stochastic process on $[0,T]$ ($t<T$) just the same as the $\sigma$-algebra induced by the subprocess on $[0,t]$?

Comment: That would at least demand that $A$ can be recognized as a probability space, wich is mostly not the case.

Comment: @drhab What do you mean? $A$ is an index set, e.g., $A=\{1,2\}$.

Comment: Never mind. It seemed to me that $X$ was meant to be a "random element" as function on $A$ prescribed by $\alpha\mapsto X_{\alpha}$. Each random element has a domain that is equipped with $\sigma$-algebra and a probability on it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is yes. The $\sigma$-algebra generated by a family of random variables $X_\alpha$, defined on common probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ each taking values in a measurable space $(\Xi_\alpha,\mathcal{X}_\alpha)$, indexed by a set $A$
$$\sigma(\{X_\alpha \mid \alpha \in A\})=\sigma(\bigcup_{\alpha \in A} \sigma(X_\alpha))$$
is the same as $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(X)$ generated by a measurable function
$$X \colon (\Omega,\mathcal{A}) \to (\prod_{\alpha \in A} \Xi_\alpha,\bigotimes_{\alpha \in A} \mathcal{X}_\alpha)$$
mapping $\omega \in \Omega$ to $u: A \to \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} \Xi_\alpha$ such that $u(\alpha)=X_\alpha(\omega)$, since product $\sigma$-algebra $\bigotimes_{\alpha \in A} \mathcal{X}_\alpha$ is generated by cylinder sets $\{u:A \to  \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} \Xi_\alpha \mid u(\alpha) \in B_\alpha\}$, $\alpha \in A$, $B_\alpha \in \mathcal{X}_\alpha$.

Comment: Note  that if $A$ is infinite this requires the axiom of choice.